# why i remain in same webpage even after logging in to website using request library in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to do a mini project in which i have to login to the website and the scrape the required  data from it. but even after sending the post request to the website i remain in same webpage. The website is
http://202.53.81.30/results/vr17r2ra/index.html

```
     from flask import Flask, render_template, request
     login_data = {'username': '198w1a0461'
                 }
     s = requests.Session()
     headers = {'User-Agent':
                  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36'}
     p = s.post('http://202.53.81.30/results/vr17r2ra/index.html', data=login_data, headers=headers)
     da = p.content
     return render_template('third.html', f=da)
```

the third .html has the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>report</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      {{f}}
   </body>
 </html>
```

the content displayed is of the same login  webpage .  what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? why send post data from the code

Comment: A captcha maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Line 244 of the source for `http://202.53.81.30/results/vr17r2ra/index.html` shows the action as a PHP script:

```
<form name=loginform METHOD=POST action=hno.php onSubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Instead of `POST`ing login data to `/results/vr17r2ra/index.html`, try `POST`ing the login data to something like `/results/vr17r2ra/hno.php`.